# Dual-Monitor Setup - only one Monitor is working

Tags: 16.04, display, intel, monitor, xserver

I installed a second DE yesterday (xfce4) and since then, my notebook/ubuntu 16.04 lts only recognizes one screen at a time.

If I plug in my VGA Kabel, the only screen working is my external monitor and vice versa if I boot with an unplugged VGA kabel, only my laptop screen works. Plugging in/out while running OS of the VGA kabel doesn't make any difference. Furthermore, it feels like it is way slower and laggy plus unity stopped with visual treats as transparency in the sidebar etc.

Measurements taken already:

- removing xfce4
- reinstalling drivers (nvidia, as well as intel)
- reinstalling lightdm
- reinstalling unity
- reinstalling xorg

Log information:

Only suspicious things I was able to detect in Xorg.0.log

```
    [     6.073] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     6.073] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     6.073] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     6.074] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[     6.074] (**) |   |-->Device "card0"
[     6.074] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     6.074] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     6.074] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     6.074] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
```

Xrandr query:

```
xrandr --query
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Oddly enough, it seems like it's also running on a refresh rate of 77.00 Hz and when I reboot without VGA connection, it displays an error about the display configuration.

I can not determine any issue right now. 
Searching for similar problems and the bugfixes didn't help so far. Does anyone have an idea about what is going on?

With best regards,

23Ro

Comment: I have EXACTLY SAME PROBLEM in 2020. What a shame ubuntu...

Comment: Not sure if I remember correctly, but:
It might have been connected to my notebook sporting a gpu integrated intel graphics unit and an additional nvidia one.

Good luck solving your issue!